# send EmitDefaultValue as a part of response

Tags: c#, wcf

I had a `DataMember` named `isActive` in `DataContract`. This member was always part of my response which was not required in most of the cases. Now I want it to be a part of one of my services, it work fine if it's value is `true` but not included in result if it is false.

How can I make this member to be always part of response for one service.

Comment: `EmitDefaultValue=true` doesn't help ?

Comment: It applies across the DataContract. I want it to be true only in one case.

Comment: do you mean _This member was **NOT** always part of my response which was not required in most of the cases_ - I am finding difficult to understand

Comment: I don't think you can selectively do that within the DataContract.   I'd suggest a separate DataContract for the cases where it is required.